# Database for Java Enterprise Edition

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee

I'm starting to use Java EE developing on Eclipse IDE, using GlassFish and the default Java database. What I should do if I want to change the database to Oracle?

The application runs on Glassfish and Google App Engine. But is there a way from Eclipse to deploy it to my own server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to deploy locally to Glassfish and Oracle using Eclipse.  (It's easy to do with IntelliJ.)

All you have to do to use Oracle is add the JDBC driver JAR to the appropriate spot in your CLASSPATH, use the new driver .class, and change the connection URL.

The driver JAR should match your JDK (e.g., ojdbc6.jar) and database version.  It should come with your database or you can download it [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/jdbc/index-091264.html).

I don't know if the JAR should go in your WEB-INF/lib or a server /lib; consult your docs to be sure.

One more thing: it goes without saying that you'll have to set up Oracle (e.g., proper credentials), create the new schema, and add the tables and indexes before you run your Java app.  I thought I'd spell it out to be safe.